# Using sahi to test sharepoint application

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, ntlm, sahi

We're trying to test sharepoint application with NTLM authentication using Sahi web testing tool. We have problem with access to the sharepoint using Sahi proxy server - we can't sign in. So if someone know this problem or know how fix it, please anserw here.

I think that problem is delegation of credentials but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Post the question on the Sahi forums (http://sahi.co.in/forums) and you should get an answer quickly.

One common mistake is to give just the username in the authentication prompt. You need to give domain\username instead.

Regards,